# Primefaces Multiple FileUpload doesn't show files nor triggers the handleFileUpload

Tags: file-upload, primefaces, uirepeat

I'm searching since one week and couldn't find a proper solution for my problem. So I'm asking the experts here.

I'm trying to implement a page with FileUpload to upload and show the images after upload on same page.

my problem is, if I set my ManagedBean to `@RequestScope`, the `handleFileUpload` function will not be triggered. 
If I set it to `@ViewScope`, the function will be triggered but the error "Error in streaming dynamic resource." is shown.

here are my files:

1. web.xml

   ```
   <filter>
   <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
   <init-param>
       <param-name>thresholdSize</param-name>
       <param-value>2097152</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <init-param>
       <param-name>uploadDirectory</param-name>
       <param-value>E:/uploadedImages</param-value>
   </init-param>
   ```

   PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter
       Faces Servlet
2. Bean

   ```
   @ManagedBean
   @RequestScoped
   public class ImageManager implements Serializable {

   private final static int MAX_UPLOADED_FILES = 5;
   private final static String UPLOADED_FILES_PATH = "E:/uploadedImages";

   private final Map<UUID, UploadedFile> uploadedFiles = new HashMap<>();

   public List<String> getListImages() {
       final List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

       for (final UUID uuid : uploadedFiles.keySet())
           result.add(uuid.toString());

       return result;
   }

   public StreamedContent getImage() {
       final ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
       final String imageId = (String) externalContext.getRequestMap().get("imageId");

       if (imageId != null) {
           final UUID imageIndex = UUID.fromString(imageId);
           return new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(uploadedFiles.get(imageIndex).getContents()), "image/jpg");
       }

       return null;
   }

   public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
       if (uploadedFiles.size() < MAX_UPLOADED_FILES) {
           final UploadedFile uploadedFile = event.getFile();
           if (uploadedFile != null) {
               uploadedFiles.put(UUID.randomUUID(), uploadedFile);
           }
       }
   }

   }
   ```
3. xhtml

   ```
                 <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{imageManager.handleFileUpload}"  
                           mode="advanced"
                           multiple="true"  
                           sizeLimit="2097152"
                           allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"
                           uploadLabel="Hochladen"
                           auto="false"
                           cancelLabel="Abbrechen"
                           invalidFileMessage="Die ausgewählte Datei ist kein zugelassene Bilddatei"
                           invalidSizeMessage="Die maximale Bildgröße ist 2MB"
                           label="Datei Auswählen"
                           update="imageList"
                           />



       <ui:repeat value="#{imageManager.listImages}" var="imageId" id="imageList">
           <h:outputText value="#{imageId}" />
           <p:graphicImage value="#{imageManager.image}">
               <f:param id="imageId" name="imageId" value="#{imageId}" />
           </p:graphicImage>
       </ui:repeat>
   ```

Comment: I think it cause of the p:graphicImage and to be more precise cause its inside ui:repeat google a bit and look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320557/how-to-use-pgraphicimage-with-streamedcontent-inside-uirepeat-hdatatable-pda and here http://stackoverflow.com/a/8068684/617373

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Daniel, blieve me. I've searched many days before I post my question here. But I have resolved the Problem by myself.

here is the solution in case that somebody has the same problem:

```
    @Controller
    @Scope(WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST)
    public class ImageManager implements Serializable {

        private final static int MAX_UPLOADED_FILES = 5;
        private final static String UPLOADED_FILES_PATH = "E:/uploadedImages";

        private final static Map<UUID, UploadedFile> uploadedFiles = new HashMap<>();

        private final static List<String> listImages = new ArrayList<>();
        private StreamedContent image;

        private static StreamedContent defaultImage = null;
        static {
            try {
                defaultImage = new DefaultStreamedContent(new FileInputStream(new File("E:\\uploadedImages\\t.jpg")), "image/jpg");
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }        
        }

        public List<String> getListImages() {
            return listImages;
        }

        public StreamedContent getImage() {
            final ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
            final String imageId = (String) externalContext.getRequestParameterMap().get("imageId");

            if (imageId != null) {
                final UUID imageIndex = UUID.fromString(imageId);
                image = new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(uploadedFiles.get(imageIndex).getContents()), "image/jpg");

                return image;
            }

            return defaultImage;
        }

        public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
            if (uploadedFiles.size() < MAX_UPLOADED_FILES) {
                final UploadedFile uploadedFile = event.getFile();
                if (uploadedFile != null) {
                    final UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
                    uploadedFiles.put(uuid, uploadedFile);
                    listImages.add(uuid.toString());
                }
            }
        }

        public void setImage(StreamedContent image) {
            this.image = image;
        }

    }
```