# How to add & display binaries on PF Galleria?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, galleria

As the PF demo of `GraphicImage`:

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/multimedia/graphicImage.xhtml?jfwid=a0c1a

(Asked on PF Forum) Using: GraphicImage I could add a single binary image by:

```
<p:graphicImage value="#{nOTiFYMotorcycleController.graphicImage}" stream="false"/>

public InputStream getGraphicImage() throws IOException {

   ...
   
   return Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(stringBuffer.toString()));
}
```

I can't see how to add a `InputStream/byte[]` in Galleria - Basic. I want to display a number of `Images` within a `<List>`?

I have also tried [Use of p:graphicImage in ui:repeat or p:dataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042517/use-of-pgraphicimage-in-uirepeat-or-pdatatable)

What I really want to do is as PF Galleria - Basic:

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/multimedia/galleria/basic.xhtml?jfwid=a0c1a

With all my Images in a 'different location' say 2 x i.e.:

```
/Users/NOTiFY/IdeaProjects/NOTiFYmoto/images/moto/MotoGuzzi/2023/V85/TT/gu9032278eun02-01-m.webp
/Users/NOTiFY/IdeaProjects/NOTiFYmoto/images/moto/MotoGuzzi/2023/V85/TT/gu9032278eun01-01-m.webp
```

Comment: What's the difference between PF Galleria showcase and your goal? What's missing?

Comment: The PF Galleria only display Images from WEB, or inside your Server WAR/EAR. It's unable to be used with a URL. I need to deploy all my Images elsewhere. See "With all my Images in a URL say 2 x:".  Hardcoded PF demo = public void init() {photos = new ArrayList<>();  photos.add(new Photo("demo/images/galleria/galleria1.jpg", "demo/images/galleria/galleria1s.jpg" "Description for Image 1", "Title 1")); etc ...

Comment: I think what he means is not really a URL but a different location on his web server. So a webapp can only serve files out of its directory it can't just grab anything from anywhere on the file system that would be a security flaw.    so it has to be a real URL like `http://somwhere`

Comment: The linked example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042517/use-of-pgraphicimage-in-uirepeat-or-pdatatable is EXACTLY your case but i had some minutes and ported this example to the primefaces showcase.... https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/9948

and no, i cant deploy it, thats up to primetek.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you serve your images via a plain Servlet?

```xml
<p:galleria value="#{bean.images}" var="image">
    <p:graphicImage value="/myImageServlet/#{image.id}"/>
</p:galleria>
```

And have a servlet like:

```
@WebServlet("/myImageServlet/*")
public class MyImageServlet extends HttpServlet {
  // parse image ID from request.getRequestURI()
  // load and serve
}
```